# Как удалить содержимое файла в си?

Tags: c

Как удалить содержимое файла в си?

Comment: [man 2 truncate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate.2.html)

Answer (score 4):

При открытии файла на запись происходит его очистка.

```
FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Удалить файл, создать новый с таким же именем.